# translate buttons on qml dialogs

Tags: android, qt, qml, translation

I am using QML [MessageDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-messagedialog.html) with a Cancel and a Yes button. My phone is set to german, but the Cancel and Yes button are not translated.

I am following the qt documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html) and added this to my main:

```
QTranslator qtTranslator;
qtTranslator.load("qt_" + QLocale::system().name(),
        QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
app.installTranslator(&qtTranslator);
```

It does not work. This code:

```
qDebug() << QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath);
qDebug() << qtTranslator.isEmpty();
```

Tells me:

1. The translation path is:  `/work/build/______________________________PADDING______________________________/translations`
2. The `qtTranslator` object is empty.

I also load a translator for my own strings, and that works.

So I do I properly initialize translation of Qt internal stings on android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want translate your application you should distrubute qt translation files with it. For android simple copy translation files to `assets` folder. Then set this path for `qtTranslator`.

You can do this with qmake. Just put this to your `.pro` file:

```
android {
    ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
    TRDESTDIR = $$system_path($$PWD/android/assets/translations)
    QMAKE_POST_LINK = $$QMAKE_COPY $$shell_path($$[QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS]/qt*_ru.qm) $$TRDESTDIR
}
```

Of course you should change `ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR` and `TRDESTDIR` to your actual location if it differs. Also you should change `qt*_ru.qm` to your language.

Then you could load translation like:

```
qtTranslator.load("qt_ru","assets:/translations")
```

Comment: Are the files copied to android/assets/translations atomaticly added to ":assets" on android? Your solution did not work for me (or I am still doing something wrong), ```qDebug() << qtTranslator.isEmpty();``` still reports ```true```.

Comment: well, it works. Only thing I have to copy it to the "android-souces" directory, not the "android" directory. Can you update your answer?

Comment: I wrote that you shoul change this path to your actual location. I mean `ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR` value. Ok, I have added this to my answer

Comment: Well, I got confused. And I think this way less people get confused by the answer :-). Thanks!